# Michael Spivak's Calculus or Tom Apostol's Calculus (2 volume series)?

Tags: reference-request

I want to get a better understanding of the inner mechanics and heart of calculus. Which book is better for this, Michael Spivak's Calculus book or Tom Apostol's Calculus(2 volume) series? What are the pros and cons of Spivak and Apostol's book/books on Calculus?

Comment: As much as I love Spivak's books, there are not comparable to Courant or Apostol books. Spivak's are mathematically beautiful but no motivation (from Physics for example) Courant's volumes 1 and 2 have no match, still the best books you can have to learn Calculus and fundamentals. Apostol's would be another good choice.

Comment: See [Spivak or Apostol?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2147994/13130) *AND* [Difficulty level of Courant's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79865/13130) *AND* [Spivak or Courant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467597/13130) *AND* [Spivak's Calculus or Courant's Calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3536920/13130)